# Jersey URL forwarding

Tags: java, url, jersey, forwarding

Inside a Jersey REST method I would like to forward to an another website. How can I achieve that?

```java
@Path("/")
public class News {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Path("go/{news_id}")
    public String getForwardNews(
        @PathParam("news_id") String id) throws Exception {

        //how can I make here a forward to "http://somesite.com/news/id" (not redirect)?

        return "";
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I'm getting the `No thread local value in scope for proxy of class $Proxy78` error when trying to do something like this:

```
@Context
HttpServletRequest request;
@Context
HttpServletResponse response;
@Context
ServletContext context;

...

RequestDispatcher dispatcher =  context.getRequestDispatcher("url");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
public Response foo()
{
    URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri(<ur url> ).build();
    return Response.seeOther( uri ).build();
}
```

I used above code in my application and it works.

Comment: You can use  Response.temporaryRedirect(location).build(); see full example here  http://www.javaproficiency.com/2015/04/redirect-in-jersey.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25332038/419348 
`seeOther` is some kind different with `temporaryRedirect`. One is `301`, and one is `302`.

Comment: This is redirect not forward.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
public String getForwardNews(

@Context final HttpServletRequest request,

@Context final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception

{

System.out.println("CMSredirecting... ");

response.sendRedirect("YourUrlSite");

return "";

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't test it right now. But why not...

Step 1. Get access to HttpServletResponse. To do it declare in your service something like:

```
@Context
HttpServletResponse _currentResponse;
```

Step 2. make redirect

```
...
_currentResponse.sendRedirect(redirect2Url);
```

**EDIT**

Well, to call forward method you need get to ServletContext. It is can be resolved the same way as response:

```
@javax.ws.rs.core.Context 
ServletContext _context;
```

Now `_context.forward` is available

Comment: I'm interested in a forward, not redirect.

Comment: @DorinGrecu just add how to get to context

Comment: @Derwy Please see my edited question, it doesn't work straight away.

Comment: ServletContext does not have a forward method.

Comment: @Fabian - sure you right, I omit some stuff. You have to use `_context.getRequestDispatcher(path)#forward`